# dask_dot RuntimeError visualizing

Tags: windows, python-3.x, graphviz, dask

I'm following the dask documentation and have installed dask[complete] and graphviz with pip, and graphviz as a system install.

`where dot` gives `...\Anaconda3\envs\compute\Library\bin\dot.bat` which points to the proper executable location.

Now running this fails:

```
import dask.array as da
x = da.ones((5,15),chunks=(5,5))
d = (x+1).dask
from dask.dot import dot_graph
dot_graph(d)
```

with
`RuntimeError: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tpng'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' path`

I'm running python 3 and dask 0.14.3 on Windows 10.

Comment: In the past there have been some issues with the conda build of `dot`, specifically with png support. Can you try with a different output type (say svg)? `dot_graph(d, format='svg')`

Comment: Hi, I get the same result but with '-Tsvg'.

Comment: What happens if you `conda install graphviz` ?

Comment: Hi, I get all requested packages already installed. Graphviz version is `2.38.0`.

Comment: I've reported the issue upstream here: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/485#issuecomment-301524698

Comment: I've just got visualization to work (solution posted in the github issue that @mrocklin posted).

Answer (score 0):

According to the anaconda packagers this should now work if you run the following:

```
conda install python-graphviz
```

Alternatively you can always install graphviz yourself using normal Windows methods.  Make sure that you `pip install graphviz` afterwards.

Comment: Neither conda install python-graphviz nor the windows installer works for me.